# Going from Java desktop programming to Android Application Developement

Tags: java, android

I know similar questions have been asked before but i think this is slightly different. for about a year Ive been learning Java. I have been building a few applications on the desktop using my-eclipse and swing GUI. Now i want to start programming for the android. I understand how to do what i want in Java but it all seems very different on android. Does anyone know of any good tutorials or videos out there with step by step instructions showing examples of android applications so that i can learn and build off of them? Most of my programs are simple and for the most part i just need to understand how to interact with the interface (IE the buttons, label or text views i think they call them and so on). I've searched all day and I cant find anything good.

Comment: i think this a too much asked question there are already plenty resources where you might get informatio just try googlethe oficial site a you're good to go, don't get me wrong is a common doubt to pass from a platform to another but is have just been asked to may times i diferents forms...

Comment: You need a new keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts) quite use full apart from the tutorials from the developers site.
If you are looking for advanced tutorials , you can try [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials).
for the most part , once you are trying a specific application , a google search could get you a relevant tutorial.
goodluck.

ps. It helps to read dev guide before you begin to write programs for android.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [Android API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html). They include a lot of simple examples which access special problems/tasks.

A more complex 'productive' application is the [Android app for the I/O conference](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/). It's Open Source - so you can have a look 'inside'.

Answer (score 1):

the Android developers site has a great dev guide and tutorials to try out. the dev guide can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). The tutorials can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend "Android Programming Tutorials" by Mark Murphy - http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/. I found the step-by-step tutorials to be very helpful, and it does focus on teaching Android development rather than Java.